# schema owner is not able to create table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

i am new to SQL DW, but have some experience with DB's

I am trying to create users (3) with different rights, but want to restrict them to one schema "dep". so i did following.

1) login to DB with super admin id. then ran following commands. all of them worked fine

```
enter code here---main db
CREATE LOGIN dep_ingestion_owner_login WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
CREATE LOGIN dep_ingestion_rw_login WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
CREATE LOGIN dep_ingestion_ro_login WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
go

---inside db "db-testing"
CREATE SCHEMA dep;
create user dep_ingestion_owner_user for login dep_ingestion_owner_login;
create user dep_ingestion_rw_user for login dep_ingestion_rw_login;
create user dep_ingestion_ro_user for login dep_ingestion_ro_login;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::dep to dep_ingestion_owner_user;
go

GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON SCHEMA :: dep TO dep_ingestion_rw_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dep TO dep_ingestion_ro_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
go
```

I am able to see schema name and users via SSMS.

Now i am trying to login with userid "**dep_ingestion_owner_login**" and selected db as => **db-testing**

login works perfectly fine. but following command is giving me error.

```
CREATE TABLE depletions_ke.Sizes (ChainID int, width dec(10,2));
```

i tried different permutations too, but getting same error.

```
CREATE TABLE [db-testing].depletions_ke.Sizes (ChainID int, width dec(10,2));
```

**Msg 6004, Level 14, State 9, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Changed database context to 'db-testing'.**

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful for you, can you pleasa accept(mark) or vote it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your code, you have create three logins and mapping with three users in database "db-testing".

You created a schema "`dep`". When a new user created without specify the schema, it will has the default schema "`dbo`".

So the three users both has the same schema `dbo`.

"`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::dep to dep_ingestion_owner_user`" means transfer ownership of the schema `dep` to user `dep_ingestion_owner_user`.

**A schema is a collection of database objects including tables, views, triggers, stored procedures, indexes, etc. A schema is associated with a username which is known as the schema owner, who is the owner of the logically related database objects.**

**Schema owner doesn't mean it is the database owner**.

You didn't grant user `dep_ingestion_owner_user` any database role, such as "db_owner". That's why you only can login to the database but have no permission to SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE.

You should add this code to grant the user as "db_owner":

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'dep_ingestion_owner_user';
```

You full code should like this:

```
enter code here---main db
CREATE LOGIN dep_ingestion_owner_login WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
CREATE LOGIN dep_ingestion_rw_login WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
CREATE LOGIN dep_ingestion_ro_login WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
go

---inside db "db-testing"
CREATE SCHEMA dep;
create user dep_ingestion_owner_user for login dep_ingestion_owner_login;
create user dep_ingestion_rw_user for login dep_ingestion_rw_login;
create user dep_ingestion_ro_user for login dep_ingestion_ro_login;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::dep to dep_ingestion_owner_user;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'dep_ingestion_owner_user';
go

GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON SCHEMA :: dep TO dep_ingestion_rw_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dep TO dep_ingestion_ro_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
go
```

Please reference:

1. [Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL
   Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).
2. [Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Only create table in schema dep ? `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'dep_ingestion_owner_user';` _db_owner only in schema dep_ ?